# Need hosting suggestion for multiple magento installation

Tags: magento-1.8, hosting

I want to install 20 magento on single hosting one domain.

this stores will be use for demo purpose not real store.

which is advisable shared hosting plan or vps or reseller plan ?

any recommendation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at what [Nexcess.net](http://www.nexcess.net/). I have years of experience with them as my host on both production & staging and their support is absolutely impeccable, they offer:

- [Dedicated](http://www.nexcess.net/magento/dedicated-servers),
- [Shared](http://www.nexcess.net/magento/hosting), and
- [Enterprise](http://www.nexcess.net/magento/enterprise-hosting) hosting plans

You mentioned needing to host 20 installations of Magento on a single server, so if you take a look at the [System Requirements](http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements), nothing really stands out apart from the 256MB of memory.

If you look at Nexcess' lowest end offering (Their SIP-100 server), this has 16GB of memory(more than 3x the requirements for your 20 x Magento installation).

I would suggest simply contacting Nexcess, explaining your requirements and they should have you up and running in next-to-no time.

You can email them at support@nexcess.net and they usually respond within minutes, alternately dial toll-free:

- US +1-866-639-2377
- UK +0-808-120-7609
- AU 1-800-765-472